# How to handle inverse in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two realm object that have inverse like this:

```
class User: Object{
  dynamic device: Device
}

class Device: Object{
  dynamic user: User
}
```

When I query the user I will get nested results, then will get message.

I have read the doc in https://realm.io, but it didn't mention about this.

So can I limit the depth of the result? Or are there better ways to achieve this? Or shoudn't I do something like this?

Thanks

***Edit:***

Change the user object to:

```
class Device: Object {
var user: User {
    return linkingObjects(User.self, forProperty: "device").first
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way! :)

Realm provides a way for child objects to perform a reverse lookup to find out their parent objects. In this case, it would logically make sense to simply have a `device` child object of `User`, and implement an inverse lookup in `Device` to find it.

In `Device`, you would implement something like this:

```
class Device: Object {
    var user: User {
        return LinkingObjects(fromType: User.self, property: "device")
    }
}
```

There's more information about this method in the ['Relationships' section](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships) of Realm Swift's documentation page.

Comment: This work 100% like what i want, can't believe i just miss this in doc. Big thanks !!